# Retrieving to-be-pushed entries in IMobileServiceSyncTable while offline

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Our mobile client app uses `IMobileServiceSyncTable` for data storage and handling syncing between the client and the server.

A behavior we've seen is that, by default, you can't retrieve the entry added to the table when the client is offline. Only when the client table is synced with the server (we do an explicit PushAsync then a PullAsync) can the said entries be retrieved.

Anyone knows of a way to change this behavior so that the mobile client can retrieve the entries added while offline?

Our current solution:

1. Check if the new entry was pushed to the server
2. If not, save the entry to a separate local table
3. When showing the list for the table, we pull from both tables: sync table and regular local table.
4. Compare the entries from the regular local table to the entries from the sync table for duplicates.
5. Remove duplicates
6. Join the lists, order, and show to the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should definitely not be happening (and it isn't in my simple tests).  I suspect there is a problem with the Id field - perhaps you are generating it and there are conflicts?

If you can open a GitHub Issue on https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues and share some of your code (via a test repository), we can perhaps debug further.

One idea - rather than let the server generate an Id, generate an Id using Guid.NewGuid().ToString().  The server will then accept this as a new Id.